# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value json

Tags: ios, swift3, urlsession

When I get data from server it will display fatal error 
below my code

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myRequest, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error != nil {
            }
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: (data)!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSMutableDictionary {
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
 do
  {
  let dict  =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

    Dispatch.main.async {
       // refresh ui like tableview[tableView.roloadData()] or collectionview
    }

  }catch{

   }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

You a have few errors in your code.

1. You are checking error for nil and deserializing json outside this check.
2. You are force unwrapping (!) data without checking it for nil.
3. You use do, but I don't see catch. Please don't use do/catch unless you really need it.

Also, I suggest you using mainThread when you already deserialized object.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myRequest) { (data, _, error) -> Void in
  guard let data = data else { return }
  let dict  =  try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
    ...
    Dispatch.main.async {
      // refresh ui
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can't use try outside of a do/catch block without converting to an optional, additionally JSONSerialization returns Any, so it must be cast, all of this however can be done in a well crafted guard statement: guard let data = data, let dict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...)) as? [String: Any] else { // error handle }

Comment: @apocolipse, my fault. Forget to add "?". As for typecasting - it depends on needs. I don't like so huge lines with so many parentheses

Comment: JSON casting is necessary.  With Swift 3.0, its default to either [Any] or [String: Any], thus returns Any so the user can pick which they cast to.
The beauty of guard/let binding to do all of that means you can put all conditions in one place and bail early if anything fails, they needn't be on a single line though, you could break it apart into 3 sections instead of 2, which eliminates the need to wrap the try? statement to avoid double optionals.